# Why -c option does not work? (ping option)

Tags: bash, ping

I would like to do a very simple thing: ping a machine. The problem is that I would like to do it only once. I made some researches and I saw that the -c option is exactly what I need. But for a reason that I don't understand, my terminal doesn't recognize it... It says "invalid option", how is it possible?

I use Cygwin on a Windows 7 Enterprise machine.

[image: Screenshot of the error message.]

Comment: replace   -c   by -n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace -c by -n.
Ｉn  **linux** you can use -c ,but in Windows and using cygwin ,you can use -n.
ｈｅｒｅ　ｉｓ　ｌｉｎｕｘ　ｍａｎ　ｐａｇｅ　ｏｆ　ｐｉｎｇ

```
     -a     Audible ping.
     -A     Adaptive  ping.  Interpacket interval adapts to round-trip time,
          so that effectively not more than one (or more,  if  preload  is
          set)  unanswered probe is present in the network. Minimal inter‐
          val is 200msec for not super-user.  On  networks  with  low  rtt
          this mode is essentially equivalent to flood mode.

   -b     Allow pinging a broadcast address.

   -B     Do  not  allow  ping  to  change  source address of probes.  The
          address is bound to one selected when ping starts.

   -c count
          Stop after sending count  ECHO_REQUEST  packets.  With  deadline
          option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the time‐
          out expires.
```

In linux **-c count**  and in  **cygwin** the option is **-n count**

Comment: I want to get the response time of that ping command, how should I do? It is very disturbing to work with a Windows command in a Linux environment. I tried to use `time` but I cannot even stock my result in a variable, I have an error.

Comment: `a=\`(time ping -c 4 www.baidu.com) 2>&1 |grep 'real' | awk '{print $2}'\`` ,you should delete all comment above

Comment: AWESOME! I would give you 1000 reputation if I could! Thank you so much for you time Mattia Dinosaur and sorry if my questions were annoying: I am a begginer in programming.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Windows ping binary, not linux's.
http://www.computerhope.com/pinghlp.htm

Consider using the appropriate option for Windows' binary (in you case I think it's `-n`)

Comment: Okay, thank you! Yes, I think you're right all the more that the information below is in French which normally is not possible with Linux. So strange that on Cygwin I have to use Windows ping command. Yes as Mattia Dinosaur said it is ping -n.

Comment: "Cygwin’s ping requires admin rights to be executed" (source :http://babun.github.io/faq.html) , maybe that's why I have to use the Windows' one (I haven't the admin rights in this computer.